# unexpected end of stream on upload

Tags: android, file, upload

I'm trying to send photos in android by streaming and this is my code

```
 FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

            // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + Config.token);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("file", fileName);
            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\";filename=\""
                    + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // create a buffer of  maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {

                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
```

but when i want to get response code from connection throws IOException and response message said Payload too large
it works perfectly when i pick a photo from camera but when i want to choose from gallery this Exception shows up

Comment: Probably image on provided path doesn't exist.

Comment: @Yupi I checked that! sourceFile exist

Comment: Please show the stacktrace. And tell which exception you have.

Comment: `but when i want to get response code from connection` There is no code where you try to do so.

Comment: You cannot use FileInputStream when you select an image from gallery as you will not get a filepath but a content uri then.

Comment: so what should i do ? @greenapps

Comment: @greenapps response message says "Payload too large" if that helps

Comment: There is no code where you try to obtain a response message.

Comment: There is no code where you try to obtain a response message.

Comment: It looks to me that the server only allows you to send small images.